# fetch response.json() gives responseData = undefined

Tags: react-native

When using fetch:

```
  fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then((response) => 
      {
        response.json() // << This is the problem
      })
    .then((responseData) => { // responseData = undefined

        console.log(responseData);
     });
     }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
     .done();
```

The following works works, do you know why? :

```
    JSON.parse(response._bodyText)
```

Comment: you need to return response.json() when you are using curly braces

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The chaining response should look more like this, specifically the `response.json` part.  Then you should get an `Object` back in `console.log`.

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {

    console.log(response)

}
```

Comment: I added `.then(response => response.json())` and it worked. Can you please tell me why is that added when it has no use?

Comment: if you do a callback with curly braces you need to `return response.json()`. The simplified form `response => response.json()` has an implicit return statement in it.

Comment: Been banging my head on the wall over this for hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 41):

Fetch is a little hard to get your head around. I am new to this so dont shoot me down if flames here but response data is another promise and you need to return response data and then handle that promise with yet another then statement where you can finally log the response, also your are missing some return statements in your promises:

```
var makeRequest = function(){

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
       return response.json() // << This is the problem
    })
    .then((responseData) => { // responseData = undefined
        addTestToPage(responseData.title);
        return responseData;
    })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  })
}

function addTestToPage(textToAdd){
   var para = document.createElement("p");
   var node = document.createTextNode(textToAdd);
   para.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  element.appendChild(para);
}

makeRequest();
```

hope that helps see: https://jsfiddle.net/byz17L4L/

Comment: In my case the 2nd `.then(responseData)` was enough. Thanks!

Comment: Good point JohnnyQ I have updated it and included a fiddle of it working with only the 2 then's

Answer (score 13):

because you didn't return response.json() in the first then.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how it finally worked out in my case:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/questions', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => { return response.json();})
    .then(responseData => {console.log(responseData); return responseData;})
    .then(data => {this.setState({"questions" : data});})

    .catch(err => {
        console.log("fetch error" + err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://........`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
```

- Use this method You can easily fatch data.

Answer (score -3):

```
fetch(weatherIng + zipCode +apiKey)
        .then(response => response.json())

      .then(response => {
     console.log(response.main);
     this.setState({
       weather: ((response.main.temp * (9/5))-459.67).toFixed(0),
       humidity:((response.main.humidity * (9/5))-459.67).toFixed(0)
     })
```

It will think that you are trying to declare something if you don't enclose it in its own:

```
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response.main);
     }) . " around the this.setState
```