# Getting individual values of a JSON Object from a Promise in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, promise

I am using the fetch method as described in the react native docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) to get data from server.

This is my code on fetching the data

```
let responseJson = await response.json();
 if(response.status>=200&&response.status<300){
    //this.setState({error:"  "});
    let alldata=responseJson;
    console.log("All data "+alldata);
 }else{
   let error=responseJson;
   throw error;
 }
 return responseJson;
```

I know that responseJson is a promise object so I have tried to resolve it like this which doesn't work.

```
  let abc= this.fetchUserDate(accessToken);
         abc.then(function(v) {
         console.log(v.Bio+" "+v.Website+"  "+typeof(v)); 
       });
```

Apart from using v.Bio I have also tried using v[0], v[1] and so on to no avail. The console prints undefined. However when I use

```
let responseJson = await response.text();
```

I get the data in plain text so there is no error on the server side. How do I get individual components of the JSON? My JSON contains basic profile information as follows:

```
  {"bio":"I am a cool guy","website":"www.cool.com","gender":"M","avatar":"/media/images/avatar/blank.png"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: javascript is not a toy language like visual basic, so, it is CaSe SeNSiTiVe - you say you tried `v.Bio+" "+v.Website+` ... but your data has `bio:` and `website:`

Comment: `responseJson` is NOT a promise object. You used await, so it's a plain javascript object. When you call `fetchUserDate` (which I assume is the name of the function from your first code sample, please clarify that) it does return a promise. Did you try to just log the result of that json you are trying to access? I realize you get undefined from it's fields, but can you tell what actually returned?

Comment: @JaromandaX using lower case characters I get the same error "undefined undefined  object" in the log

Comment: @MotiAzu the fetchUserDate is the function being called, I have tried logging the JSON object but end up getting the following in the console "[Object object]". When I try to resolve it with .bio or .website I get it as undefined. Although the .text() method shows that all the data is being received. Please do look at Akis answer too...

Comment: Please edit your question with whole functions so we can see where the problems are.

Comment: also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined

Answer (score -1):

You are calling response.text(). Try calling response.json().

This is from the docs

```
try {
let responseJson = await response.json();
console.log(responseJson);
      return responseJson;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

You have to use the response inside the try block because it would not be resolved instantly.

Try doing console.log on the responseJson object to see what actually comes back. As @Jaromanda-x suggested, use the objects as you see it i.e. case sensitive.

Comment: I am using a try catch block, the problem is resolving the response of the returned object to get its individual components

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(responseJson)?

Comment: It just says undefined in the log