# Didnt Get the Response Json From Post Method React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I Tried to fetch data from my web api and the request method is Post, the body for the post method is from AsyncStorage that i get from the login user. After that the resPonseJson is saved to my state dataSource, after that i'm using flatlist to shows the data. But the data is not shows up , when i try to fetch data from Get Method the data  shows inmy flatlist, but when i tried to use the Post Method

```
componentDidMount(){
  let FirstName = this.state.FirstName;
return fetch('http:example.com/api/select', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
   FirstName: FirstName,
 }),

})
.then((response) => response.json())  
.then((responseJson) => {

  this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    dataSource: responseJson,
  }, function(){

  });

})
.catch((error) =>{
  console.error(error);
});
}

 render() {


    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
       <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.LastName}, {item.Gender}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

so whats the problem in here, as you can see my web api is fine , and i check my FirstName state in  is have the data from AsyncStorage too, there is no error message, any suggestion here ? thanks

**UPDATE** 
i think i know whats going on here, when i tried to hardcode the FirstName in body it works well, but when i change the body to state it will not work, any suggestion here

Answer (score 0):

The chaining response should look more like this, specifically the response.json part. Then you should get an Object back in console.log.

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {

console.log(response);
```

Comment: and so dataSpurce setState , willl be like this dataSource : console.log(response);   ?

Comment: Use .then(response => response.json()) then it worked.

Comment: if you do a callback with curly braces you need to return response.json(). The simplified form response => response.json() has an implicit return statement in it.

Comment: hi im sorry but its look like you just copying from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined ,

Comment: Hi  @Theodorus Agum Gumilang, I'm using it cause it's worked to me.

Comment: but this is doesnt work, maybe beacause im using Post Method ? and post method cant get the response.json ?