# Get object value that has numeric key in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I getting data as object like below:

```
{
    "Version": "AAA",
    "Schema" : "AAA",
    "Total"  : 432234,
    ....
    "Content": {
        "1" : {
            "1" : {
                ...
            },
            "2" : {
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the values from the numeric key in react native?
something like this:

```
var first_numeric_key = 1;
var second_numeric_key = 2;
aboveObject.Content[first_numeric_key][second_numeric_key];
```

I tried with the below script but still getting issues.

```
aboveObject.Content["1"]
```

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this4.state.contents.content["1"])

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Is it a JavaScript object or a JSON object? JSON needs to be parsed first.

Comment: @Ties, I used fetch() function to get the data from the website source url.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined). You may need to add `.then(response => response.json())`.

Comment: Yeah of course, like this: fetch(rightURL)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(responseJson => {
                this.setState({ 
                    contents: JSON.parse(responseJson)
                });
            })

Comment: Did you already do that?

Comment: Yes, when I try to use that contents, I'm getting this issue: "TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this4.state.contents.content.["1"])"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a React Native guy but this seems more like a JavaScript syntax nuance.

You can access object keys as `obj['key']`

Here, in your case, it will be

```
aboveObject.Content['1']['2']
```

Updating answer after OP's edit to the question

```
const first_numeric_key = 1;
const second_numeric_key = 2;
aboveObject.Content[first_numeric_key.toString()][second_numeric_key.toString()];
```

> **EDIT**

This is working without convert to the string

```
aboveObject.Content[first_numeric_key][second_numeric_key]
```

The issue was the exception handling, since there was some delaying when the app get the data from the fetch() function so the aboveObject was null at the very first time.

Comment: Yeah this is working actually, the issues was because of there was some delay to get json data so need to add exception handling,

Comment: If this solution solved your problem, can you mark the answer as accepted? It will help others stumbling across the same problem.

Comment: And it is working without convert to string - aboveObject.Content[first_numeric_key][second_numeric_key]