# fetch body (response.text()) is returning empty

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
var getURL = "someUrl.com"

fetch(getURL)
.then(response => {
   //console.log(response.status)
  //returns 200, confirms this works
  //console.log(response.text())
  //I can see the text being printed out in the console and its HTML
  // I can also see a Promise is being fulfilled
  response.text()
})
.then(text => {
  console.log(text)
  // this is returning as undefined
})
```

What am I doing that is causing `console.log(text)` to return as undefined?

Comment: You need to return `response.text()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch response.json() gives responseData = undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking to `return` the value of `response.text()` to your next `.then()` block:

```
fetch(getURL)
.then(response => {
  return response.text()
})
.then(text => {
  console.log(text)
})
```

You can learn more about this use of Promise chaining in [this javascript.info article](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

Comment: I think this question is a typo or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined