# API response returning UNDEFINED in react native

Tags: react-native

API response returning UNDEFINED in react native
and I am getting error in console like this -> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response[0]')

here is my code

```
ListView = () => 
    {
   AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by"]).then(response => {
         console.log(response[0][1]) // Value1
         console.log(response[1][1]) // Value2

    fetch("https://xyz.tech/Android_API_CI/get_lead_data_for_user", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify([{ id:response[1][1], application_id:response[0][1]}]),
    })
      .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
  })
        .then((response) => {
 alert(response)
           console.log(response)  

            this.props.navigation.navigate("ListView", {
              application_id:response[0][1],
               created_by:response[1][1],  
            });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      Alert.alert("some Thing wrong")
    }
```

Comment: Could u include the code of writing to `AsyncStorage` ?

Comment: const items = [['application_id', response[0].data[0].application_id], ['created_by', response[0].data[0].id]];
          AsyncStorage.multiSet(items, () =>

Comment: I'm not sure if  `response[0].data[0].application_id` contains valid-value ... but you could do something like 
  `try {
    await AsyncStorage.multiSet([firstPair, secondPair]);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('error multiset', e);
  }` to make sure `multiset` is done correctly ... besides, it's always a good practice to check if `response`  content is not `null` before attempting to access it...

Comment: Similar question solved in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined